# Many Postgres.exe process

Tags: postgresql, process

There are many postgres.exe process in my computer, even if I'm not activating my PosgreSQL. Why does postgres has many process? unlike MySQL and the others. Any explanation?

Comment: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/FAQ#Why_does_PostgreSQL_have_so_many_processes.2C_even_when_idle.3F

Comment: @Stephen: you should make that an answer!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why so many "postgres.exe" are created when I run my application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849536/why-so-many-postgres-exe-are-created-when-i-run-my-application)

Answer (score 1):

Postgresql Server has many process such as autovacuum process,wal writer process ,stats collector process ,writer process whose parent's process is Postgres process.