# Why so many "postgres.exe" are created when I run my application?

Tags: postgresql

I have a J2EE application, deployed in JBoss6 application server in **Windows (Vista 32 bit)** platform. My database is "**PostgreSQL 9.0.4**" and I am using JDBC driver: "postgresql-9.0-801.jdbc4.jar".

In my ds.xml file, I have defined **max-pool-size = 75** and min-pool-size = 40.
i am using JPA/Hibernate as well as using javax.sql.DataSource.

In windows "Task Manager", I find that when PostgreSQL server starts up it creates **6 "postgres.exe" processes**.
Now when I deploy/start my J2EE application in JBoss, I find a **total of 66** "postgres.exe" processes.
So that means another **60 postgres processes** were spawned (or launched) because of my application started.

If I change the **max-pool-size** to be **40** then I notice that I have a total of **46 postgres.exe processes**.
In both cases the no. of postgres processes comes down to 6 when I stop my J2EE application.

So my question, is this normal?
Are those extra processes spawned/launched because of 'connection pooling' (used by Hibernate)?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, this is normal. From the [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/tutorial-arch.html):

> The PostgreSQL server can handle multiple concurrent connections from
>   clients. To achieve this it starts ("forks") **a new process for each
>   connection**. From that point on, the client and the new server process
>   communicate without intervention by the original postgres process.
>   Thus, the master server process is always running, waiting for client
>   connections, whereas client and associated server processes come and
>   go.

Comment: Hi @Frank I am facing same problem due to which my DB interaction performed by spring-boot application has became slow. Is there any way to close unnecessary connection ? how can i optimise this ?

Comment: It seems like it doesn't close the processes.

Comment: Did anyone discover how to close "unused" process? it only increases, never close

Comment: but why does it create new process? why not use multithreading instead?

Comment: @ApurvaSingh: Because they made the choice to go with a new process.